# How to create a checkbox in VisualForce page ? Check the state whether it is checked or not?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Do I need to create a custom field first in the object ?

If **yes**, lets say I have created a custom field `Active__c` so following will be my VF page code ?

`<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Active__c}"/>`

Comment: With a standard controller it would be `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!MyCustomObject.Active__c}"/>` or with a custom controller `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCustomObjectPropertyName.Active__c}"/>`.

Comment: `apex:inputCheckBox` need not be bound to a custom field of type Checkbox - you can bind to a controller Boolean variable with a public getter/setter

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where you are checking state. If on the page you can use Javascript / jQuery

```
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Active__c}" id="my_chk_bx" onchange="is_checked();"/>

<script>
function is_checked(){    
     var is checked = $('[id$=my_chk_bx]').prop('checked',true); 
}
</script>
```

will get you the stated of the checkbox.

If you are doing it in the controller, you can add an

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" ..... />
```

to the checkbox to call a method in the controller to check the state and do what you need.

To do what you asked in your comment below something like:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Active__c}" id="my_chk_bx" >
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="txt_panel"/>
 </apex:InputCheckBox>
 <apex:outPutPanel id="txt_panel" layout="inline">
     <apex:outPutText value="{!IF(Active__c,'Approved','Not Approved')}"/>
 </apex:outPutPanel>
```

Comment: thank u for the reply. so lets say I am doing it on the page level, and if the user clicks on check...I want to display a text besides the checkbox saying _Approved_ and by default when it is not checked I want it to show _Not Approved_. Is this possible ?

Comment: @sus - See updated answer